# how to put non removable credit link

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

I want to put a non removable credit link on my blogger templates but I don't know how. I have seen many templates using it but they are revealing their secrets.
All of them obfuscate their codes.
This is the below that I want to hapen.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" id="credit">Site name</a>
```

When they change the example.com - they will be redirected to example.com
when they remove or change the class "credit" they will be redirected..

They are putting their javascript code before .

Comment: That's fundamentally impossible... Anybody who is more clever/motivated than you is going to figure out a way around it.

Comment: Publish the templates! Put your name on them now. You won't necessarily get recognition every time somebody uses one, but you can always win an argument about it. Also, ask for recognition - plenty of people will honestly forget, and this reminder will be enough.

Comment: Everything is possible but Pros are not listed here...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can but you have to use a `JQuery` in your template for this.

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function()
{
var aa=$("#mycredit").val();
if (aa == null) {
    window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/";
};
$("#mycredit").attr("href","
http://www.example.com/");
});
//]]>
</script>
```

And after adding above code, add the below code in your footer where you want to write your credit link...

```
<div id='#mycredit'>
Designed By <a href='http://www.example.com/' id='#mycredit'>Example Company</a>
</div>
```

Replace the URL from above to your on in both codes. Now for safty, Encrypt the above JQuery with your  Blogger Template other JQuery using [**Javascript Obfuscator**](http://javascriptobfuscator.com/)

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, in your example code "credit" is an ID and not a class.

If you are selling or giving other people HTML code and associated JavaScript and CSS for use on their own site, it is impossible to prevent them from changing or adding to it. Whilst you could obsfucate a click event handler that directs to your site, which may be nontrivial to locate and remove, it does not help in circumstances where the link has simply been removed from the HTML by the user - or hidden using CSS. Testing for all possible methods of hiding the link (positioning, visibility, display, opacity, text-indent, colour, height/width etc.) will be onerous and a losing battle.

Assuming the user did simply change the credit link to point to their own site, **and** could not find and locate the click handler that directs visitors to your site instead - it would be easy for them to provide their *own* click handler which directs to their site **and** stops propagation to stop your handler being called.

To avoid the user removing the link, or changing the URL, in your HTML template you *could* add it to the page using JavaScript but - even if you could prevent the user from removing this code through obsfucation - any CSS rules applied to the page will still be applied, allowing the user to hide it, and it could be trivially removed from the DOM using their own scripts. Search engines also will most likely not see the link, even if left unchanged, as JavaScript may not be evaluated by visiting bots.

In summary, by all means seek credit for your work, and leave a link in your template - but there is no technical way you can guarantee that it will not be changed or removed once run on the sites of your end users. The best method would probably be to require that the link remains, and points to your site, in the license for use of the template.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jquery. There is a easy way to add this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            //Let's first setup the redirect
        function redirect(){
            window.location.assign('http://www.example.com');
        }

            //which things we got to check
        function check(){
                if($('#credits').length === 0){
                    redirect();
                }

                else if($('#creditlink').length === 0){
                    redirect();
                }

                else if($("#creditlink").attr("href") !== "http://www.example.com"){
                    redirect();
                }

                else if($('#creditlink').text() !== "Site name"){
                    redirect();
                } 
            }
        //execute the function on page load
        check();
        //excute the function at the intervals of 5 seconds.
        setInterval(function () {check()}, 5000);
        });
```

This program will better help you to add non removable credit link. But for which you need to add the HTML somthing like this

```
<div id="credits">  
            <a id="creditlink" href="http://www.example.com">Site name</a>
</div>
```

---

Reference: http://themedaddy.net/lets-learn-to-protect-your-work-with-non-removable-credit-links/